# can php session expire while sending a post ?

Tags: php, session-timeout

Basically, a php session won't expire while a user is surfing on a website. But "while the user is surfing on the website" means that there are get and post requests. Nevertheless, i can't figure out if there has to be new requests, or if one active request is enough to maintain the session…

For instantce, i have a big file upload by post. It could then take hours. Will the session expire or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lifetime of a session depends on the ini setting [`session.gc-maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime). Every access to the session (read and write) resets the timer. After the timeout, when the session garbage collector runs, the session values are destroyed.

The default value is 1440, which means 24 minutes. So if you have hits that access the session in any way at least every 24 minutes, the session values will stay.

If you need the session to stay alive longer than that, you can extend the timeout with `ini_set` (use before `session_start()`), for example:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 24*60*60); // 24 hours
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually knew it lasted 24 minutes, but i'd prefer not to extend this lifetime (as it will take longer to release some memory). Anyway, if i understood well, as my upload is going on, it hits the session so it won't expire, even if the upload lasts more than 24mn.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't. Usually when I work with $_SESSION's, they last for a day or so. But it might on some servers. In that case you need to add cookies, too. With cookies you can exactly manipulate the time the person can be online for.

Comment: Sorry, nothing about this answer is correct. In the standard configuration, the session cookies will stay until the browser is closed. The session will work indefinitely if you keep accessing it within the session.gc-maxlifetime timeout.

Comment: Perhaps that's why it lasts for a day - I never close my browser, however it is configurable and cookies are for long lifetime usage. So I don't really much of incorrectness in that answer.

Comment: session might still be there, but the informations you store into them fade away. Actually there's only the session's id that is stored in a cookie, the session's related infos are in the server's memory. And what i need is the related infos (that expire after the value set in session.gc_maxlifetime). Are you still getting the $_SESSION array after a day or two with default session.gc_maxlifetime value ?! Cause the server doesn't know if your browser is closed or not…